# exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm creating a custom filter by inheriting `RFPDupeFilter`.
Here is the link from which I'm using the code:
https://github.com/j4s0nh4ck/wiki-spider/blob/master/wiki/wiki/SeenURLFilter.py

Note: I have above code in a custom file named custom_filters.py in the same directory where settings.py resides then in settings.py I have this code.

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'myspider.custom_filters.SeenURLFilter'
```

But when I run the bot, I get this error:

> exceptions.TypeError: `__init__()` takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: How do you call this spider ?

Comment: I'm behind spider with persistance so using this command to call spider 'scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1'.... but I get that error even without persistance command. i.e 'scrapy crawl somespider'.

Comment: can you post full traceback?

Comment: Could you provide a longer stack-trace because this error code can be anything.

Comment: 2015-09-29 14:33:34 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-09-29 14:33:34 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
................ File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 28, in from_crawler
    dupefilter = dupefilter_cls.from_settings(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/dupefilters.py", line 44, in from_settings
    return cls(job_dir(settings), debug)
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: May I know why did I get negative vote to my question?

Comment: Try changing the constructor of your filter class to the following: `def __init__(self, path=None, debug=False):`

Comment: I did that following this link https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L31. but that dint help either.

Comment: The counts in that `TypeError` look wrong. The code you linked would accept 1-2 arguments (`self` required, `path` optional), so it should be telling you `TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`, not `exactly 1 argument`). Are you sure you're using the code you linked?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the traceback `from_settings()` method of your filter is called - it then creates an instance of your custom dupe filter. But, since you don't specify your own `from_settings()` method [the one from built-in `RFPDupeFilter` is used](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/457b97c13ccf9a84f3dc7800c180cf059822c09a/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L42-L45):

```
@classmethod
def from_settings(cls, settings):
    debug = settings.getbool('DUPEFILTER_DEBUG')
    return cls(job_dir(settings), debug)
```

which tries to instantiate your custom dupe filter with `path` and `debug` constructor arguments. And your `SeenURLFilter` constructor does not accept `debug` argument.

You need to have your dupefilter accepting [`debug` parameter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/457b97c13ccf9a84f3dc7800c180cf059822c09a/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L31) as well:

```
from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter

class SeenURLFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    """A dupe filter that considers the URL"""

    def __init__(self, path=None, debug=False):  # FIX WAS APPLIED HERE
        self.urls_seen = set()
        RFPDupeFilter.__init__(self, path, debug)  # AND HERE

    def request_seen(self, request):
        if request.url in self.urls_seen:
            return True
        else:
            self.urls_seen.add(request.url)
```

Comment: To avoid mirroring stuff like default arguments that might change (and you're agnostic about), it's probably best to make it `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): ... RFPDupeFilter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` so you use the super class's default arguments directly when appropriate, rather than copying them into your own prototype and assuming they'll never change.